# Gson deserialize models within a wrapper

Tags: java, json, gson

I've got a collection of potential JSON response models within a wrapper class, such as this Dashboard example:

```
public class Dashboard {

    @SerializedName("dashboard")
    private List<Wrapper> wrappers;

    public class Wrapper {

         LocalDateTime updated;

         SingleItemModel item;

         ItemCollectionModel items;

         //....

    }
}

public class ItemCollectionModel {

      List<SingleItemModel> items;

}
```

I'm trying to populate these fields from an aggregated JSON of several API endpoints.  An abbreviated form looks similar to this:

```
{
   "dashboard": [
   {
      "updated": "2017-02-08T05:42:52.451",
      "items": {...}
    },
      "updated": "2017-02-08T05:42:52.451",
      "item": {...}
    },
    ....
    ]
}
```

I'm having an issue where Gson is failing to create the POJOs.  If my understanding is correct, the default deserialization attempts to match the field name with the JSON element key.

```
"items" : {} to ItemCollectionModel items
```

I think the problem is that the instance fields are named similarly to their Wrappers counterpart.

```
Wrapper.items vs ItemCollectionModel.items
```

The Gson deserialization works perfect when the API response is a single POJO, it treats the encapsulating JSON object as the POJO and the inner values of the JSON are matched to the POJO fields.  But I'm getting null fields when attempting to use the Wrapper.

How can I ensure that the Wrapper's fields are correctly deserialized?

------------UPDATE-------------

A simple solution was staring me in the face.  Using a List of objects, per jakubbialkowski's answer, allows Gson to deserialize the items.  The trick was to then just manually create the CollectionModel to encapsulate it when the getter for the field is called.

```
public ItemCollectionModel getItemCollectionModel() {
    return new ItemCollectionModel(items);
}
```

Comment: You can generate pojos online to pass your json .

Comment: could you provide more explanation to this?

Comment: To make proper pojo structure for gson from json , pass your json response to in http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/  this links and select Source type: and Annotation style: at right side .

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace :

```
ItemCollectionModel items;
```

with:

```
List<SingleItemModel> items;
```

Comment: You're correct that this would allow Gson to deserialize the response but the collections classes are required to determine the view type to display.